# Расширенный поиск для Wordpress.

Tags: wordpress

Существует сайт на wordpress. Сайт о разных рецептах. Так как рецептов много, используя одно меню и на поиск конкретного блюда тратится много времени. Необходимо оптимизировать поиск блюд. Мне нужно реализовать: поиск  с чекбоксами, которые являются меткмами и рубриками (можно ограничиться одними лишь метками, но было бы здорово если были бы и метки). Помогите пожалуйста создать такой поиск, собственных сил не хватило.

Comment: @Никита Кузнецов, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Если достаточно поиска по рубрикам или тегам (на самом деле и то и другое частный случай таксономий, так-что особой разницы между ними нет) то это (кажется) просто ещё один параметр для wp_query, можно задать просто через URL.

Например если URL рубрики `http://uft.me/category/category-name` (если используются ЧПУ) то поиск строки постов содержащих стоку `foo` и находящихся в рубрике `category-name` это `http://uft.me/category/category-name?s=foo`

Если нужно что-то большее чем поиск по таксономиям, например найти все рецепты требующие не более полчаса времени (или не более 10 грамм сахара, или содержащие на менее 500 ккал на 100 грамм), то почитай про [произвольные поля и их использование совместно с wp_query](http://wpmag.ru/2014/rabota-s-proizvolnyimi-polyami-v-wp_query/).

И почитай про sphinx, или другие подобные системы, приходится когда найгрузка возростёт настолько что собственный поиск WP станет слишком медленным.